# Array of JButtons is returning void

Tags: java, swing

I'm attempting to create Minesweeper and I've managed to get stuck very early on with my array of JButtons returning void instead of a JButton so therefore I can't perform any actions on it.

Here is the code: (The error occurs in the last line when I want to remove the button)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   JButton[][] buttons;
   int rows;
   int cols;
   int x;
   int y;

   public Game(int rows, int cols)
   {
      setTitle("Minesweeper");
      setSize(500, 500);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.rows = rows;
      this.cols = cols;
      setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
      buttons(rows, cols);
   }
   public void buttons(int tableX, int tableY)
   {

      buttons = new JButton[tableX][tableY];

      for (x = 0; x < tableX; x++)
      {
         for (y = 0; y < tableY; y++)
         {
            buttons[x][y] = new JButton(); 
            buttons[x][y].setActionCommand("Pressed");
            buttons[x][y].addActionListener(this);
            this.add(buttons[x][y]);            
         }
      }
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      for (x = 0; x < rows; x++)
      {
         for (y = 0; y < cols; y++)
         {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Pressed"))
            {
               buttons[x][y] = setVisible(false);
            }
         }
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `=` for invoking methods

```
buttons[x][y].setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `setVisible()` is a stand alone method? try `buttons[x][y].setVisible(false);`

setVisible is a method that belongs to the JButton Object so you can't just arbitrarily call it. Think "What is being set to visibile?"

Currently you're getting a returned void because what you're actually calling is a method in your immediate class called `setVisible()` (which doesn't exist therefor returns void) when you want to call the JButton's `setVisibile`

Comment: He doesn't get a null pointer exception, he gets a compile time error because setVisible(false) does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

you might don't want to hide them, you can do

```
buttons[x][y].setEnable(false);
```

when you do that you can change the icon on them according to what is behind them